# How to pass Bootstrap-Variables in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I try to pass Bootstrap Variables to other files in Rails - and fail.

My `application.css.scss` looks like this:

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
*/

/* Import own Vars */
@import 'myvars';

/* Import Twitter Bootstrap */
@import 'bootstrap';

/* Import own layout */
@import 'custom';
```

When I create a `$testVar: 100px;` in `_myvars.scss` and try to use it in `custom.css.scss` it´s not working - the page fails to load and I get an `Undefined variable: "$testVar".`-Error

It works when defining the variable directly in `custom.css.scss` but I´d rather have a overview-file with all my variables (like I used to have when using TB as a standalone). I´m very new to Rails, so please be patient :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Bootstrap natively uses LESS, not SASS for it's CSS preprocessor. To mix them together, make sure you are using the SASS gemified version, which is unofficial. [See here](https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass)

Comment: Everything good on that front ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to remove `*= require_tree .` . Check this [screen cast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/268-sass-basics?view=asciicast) for more info.

Comment: You hit it again! Thanks alot!!